# 1980s/1990s movie where teens gain powers after death

Tags: story-identification, movie

It was a 1980s or 1990s movie where powers awaken after death. The plot is fuzzy but I remember a pole going through a young man’s body and when he is pulled out it heals. It also awakens psychokinetic powers. He is not the only one and there are others like him. The movie was in English. I though the name was Warlock but that’s not right name. I think a dad kills his son to awaken powers but I can be mixing movies.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Please [edit] your question to add as many more details as you can think of, including where you saw this, the language it was in, if it was live-action, what kind of power the teen has, etc.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons on the answer, as per the [tour]. (If the checkmark doesn't appear, you may not be logged into the original account)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is [*Warlock: The Armageddon*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warlock:_The_Armageddon) (AKA *Warlock II*).

> In the present, Kenny Travis and Samantha Ellison, a young man and
> woman, are in love but are having relationship issues. Their parents
> are Druids; while Samantha's father Ted Ellison is a priest and has
> neglected his responsibilities as a Druid, **Kenny's father Will Travis
> kills Kenny so he can rise again with the aid of Druid magic to become
> a Druid warrior.**